# Get Jar output in vb and send commands

Tags: vb.net, jar

really need help! I would like to know how to get jar output into a textbox in VB 2008.
Also i would like to send commands to it (like CMD would when you use this command: 
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe -Xms128M -Xmx1024M -jar Craftbukkit.jar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below a proof of concept. You'll have to tweak it to your own desires and wishes. What does this do:

1. Start a process in the background
2. Start reading the output and error streams.
3. You can send commands via a textbox (and a click on a button).
4. Write the output/errors in an output textbox.

Again, this code is just a proof of concept, it is far from finished (but it demonstrates enough). You'll have to add some extra checks etc to make it "waterproof".

```
Public Class MyForm
    Private WithEvents _CmdProcess As Process
    Private Delegate Sub DisplayTextDelegate(text As String)

    Private Sub MyForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim processInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
        processInfo.FileName = "cmd"
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        processInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = True

        _CmdProcess = Process.Start(processInfo)
        _CmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()
        _CmdProcess.BeginErrorReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyForm_Disposed(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Disposed
        If _CmdProcess IsNot Nothing Then
            _CmdProcess.Close()
        End If
        _CmdProcess = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExecute_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExecute.Click
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCommand.Text) Then
            Dim inputStream As System.IO.StreamWriter = _CmdProcess.StandardInput
            inputStream.WriteLine(txtCommand.Text)
            inputStream.Flush()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CmdProcess_ErrorDataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs) Handles _CmdProcess.ErrorDataReceived
        Invoke(New DisplayTextDelegate(AddressOf DisplayText), Environment.NewLine)
        Invoke(New DisplayTextDelegate(AddressOf DisplayText), "Error!")
        Invoke(New DisplayTextDelegate(AddressOf DisplayText), e.Data)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CmdProcess_OutputDataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs) Handles _CmdProcess.OutputDataReceived
        Invoke(New DisplayTextDelegate(AddressOf DisplayText), e.Data)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DisplayText(text As String)
        txtOutput.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
        txtOutput.AppendText(text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @THUND3R If it is the answer to your question, could you mark it as the answer?